# Empty Compose Activity template not found in Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use Android Studio Flamingo to learn more about Jetpack Compose but I can't find the Empty Compose Activity template.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlrdy.png) is what I see.

I tried upgrading to the beta version of Android Studio Giraffe but it still not showing the template.

Comment: The thing you've got selected on photo is "Empty Compose Activity" :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio Flamingo, there are updates to the project templates.
Basically you can say that `Empty Compose Activity` is now `Empty Activity`. See the [Updates to project templates](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-flamingo-release-notes#updates-to-npw-nmw) section of the [Android Studio Flamingo release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases) for more information.